# WordPress Theme: What is the right way to put inline CSS loading from a CSS file

Tags: theme-development

So, I have the main Wordpress Theme file, the `style.css`, and I would like to add some inline CSS to the header.

For that, I have a separated CSS file, mainly for organisation and because is more easy to maintain.

I also use the `wp_add_inline_style` to properly inline the CSS code after the main linked CSS code.

The problem is, because the inline code is in a separated CSS file, and I need to use some the PHP function `file_get_contents`, and to my knowledge this is not advisable to Wordpress Themes. Or is it?

I search options around the web and StackExchange and found:

One was using `wp_remote_get`, but I don't think this is the right function for this (may be I am wrong).

Other alternative, that I have read was using `ob_start`, `include` and `ob_get_clean`, but this seems must worse than `file_get_contents`.

Other alternative that I have read was using [Filesystem_API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API), but this seems unnecessary and adds complexity to theme for just a simply thing.

I don't what to put the CSS code inside the `function.php` or any other PHP file. And I would like to do this the **Right Way as possible**!

Heres the code:

```
wp_register_style(
    'my-theme-style',
    get_stylesheet_uri(),
    array(),
    '',
    'screen'
);
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-theme-style' );
wp_add_inline_style(
    'my-theme-style',
    file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/inline.css')
);
```

Thanks for any Help!

Comment: Who told you`using `file_get_contents` is "not advisable"? If you know what your doing, you can use it perfectly fine. I'm not sure how it works, if this creates an actual HTTP request, I personally would prefer the `ob_start` / `include` / `ob_get_clean` way because no HTTP requests are involved.Since you've already posted some code: Does the current solution work and you're simply asking if there is a better way for it?

Comment: Why not just enqueue the `inline.css` file directly?

Comment: What you have provided above `file_get_contents()` is the method I usually use. It works very well.

Comment: `file_get_contents` would be fine for this use-case, but Tom is right, why does this need to be inline? Why not just enqueue the file?

Comment: Let me reinforce that this is a question about Wordpress Theme Development Best Practices.  So, @kero answering your question, yes I am looking for a better way with the Best Practices in mind, I guess. And I have read that theme verifiers check for this, but i am not 100% sure…

Comment: @GaryL I my opinion I think is fine also, but reading about a lot of different stuff and opinions, and starting to get confused with the lack of actual data …so, StackExchange community to the rescue.

Comment: @TomJNowell, currently it uses enqueue, but I want to upgrade the theme for speed improvements. And, calling a lot of CSS, adds HTTP requests, also CSS is Render Blocking. So, some inline CSS code resolves some of this.

Comment: That's not an issue with HTTP2, especially if you preload or use HTTP2 push. Eitherway, the **most** efficient method is to prebuild, not to inline. Inlining increases the cost and prevents the browser from doing things in parallel, and it guarantees a render blocking event. Perhaps in a HTTP1 world what you say is true, but we've been using HTTP1.1 for decades, and HTTP2 is widespread, and you can use SASS style stuff to spread your CSS across lots of modular files then build a single monolithic final stylesheet

Comment: @TomJNowell, unfortunately you made wrong assumptions. For your information, I already use SASS to pre build. Also, some part of the CSS needs to be separated. I understand that you have an opinion, but I was looking for valid data and resources. Thanks!

Comment: If that's the case, you can apply CSS to different pages using the classes added via the `body_class` and `post_class` functions in the theme. You ask what the right way to do this is, and the appropriate answer is **you don't**, there are always superior mechanisms and methods. If you shared with us what the root problem was I might have been able to share some of those

Comment: @TomJNowell I have consider that option, but opted to look first to embed part of the CSS in the head. That is where my question, arose. Both work for the propose intended (variations / customisations to the theme). But, I will consider the other option, as well as your input and experience (and others comments), and give a better thought to my options. But still, I would like to know if there is a answer to my specific question, regarding putting CSS code in the head. But from the current feedback, probably there isn't just one, or a right answer, as you say. Thank!